# Typescript single-file compilation does not include interfaces

Tags: typescript

**Background**

I need to create an adapter for an existing Javascript package in Typescript.  This requires both creating definition files for the existing package, and writing some classes that build on top of those interfaces.  I will need to reuse the resulting Typescript package in multiple projects.

To create this package I'm using a C# Class Library project, but there are no C# types defined, and I am only using it for Typescript.  The Typescript compiler is set to output a single `*.js` and `*.d.ts` file.

**Problems**

When I compile, classes defined in my `*.ts` files can be found in the output `*.d.ts` file, but any interfaces defined in `*.d.ts` files do not show up in the output.  Several methods in my classes use those interfaces as return types, so when I try to reuse the package, I get a "Cannot find name 'xxx'." compiler error for the missing interfaces.

**Some code:**

Here is one of the interfaces that is disappearing:

```
declare module IS_Interface
{
    export interface Iterable<T>
    {
        hasMoreElements(): boolean;
        nextElement(): T;
    }
}
```

All of the Typescript files in this project are in the `IS_Interface` module.  The declaration files start with `declare module IS_Interface` and the *.ts files just start with `module IS_Interface`.

Here is a class that consumes the interface (it will show up in the *.d.ts file):

```
module IS_Interface
{
    export class IterableUtil
    {
        static ToArray<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) : Array<T>
        {
            let result = new Array<T>();

            while(iterable.hasMoreElements())
            {
                result.push(iterable.nextElement());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my compiler settings:

```
{PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"}
    {TypeScriptNoImplicitAny}True{/TypeScriptNoImplicitAny}
    {TypeScriptOutFile}bin/debug/IS_Adapter.js{/TypeScriptOutFile}
    {TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations}True{/TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations}
    {TypeScriptNoEmitOnError}True{/TypeScriptNoEmitOnError}
{/PropertyGroup}
```

All of the Typescript and declaration files are in "TypeScriptCompile Include" tags in my project file.

**Questions**

- Is there a way to output interfaces from Typescript compilation?
- Is this not how Typescript interfaces are intended to be used?
- Is there a simpler way to create a Typescript package that doesn't require a C#/VB project?
- Should I not be splitting modules across files like this?  Does it matter that parts of my module are declared and parts are not?

**Update**

@Martin - I've removed the module declarations.  I'm very confused about namespace/module resolution in Typescript.  Are modules primarily physical groupings or logical groupings?  Are they kind of both?  Most of my experience is with desktop/server programming in C#, where there is a clear assembly vs namespace distinction.

Here is some simplified code:

Note, in my output *.d.ts file, I still have my import statement, but it is a broken reference.

`MyInterface.d.ts`:

```
export interface Iterable<T>
{
    hasMoreElements(): boolean;
    nextElement(): T;
}
```

`MyConsumer.ts`:

```
import { Iterable } from "./MyInterface";

export class Thing
{
    Name: string;
    Thing: Iterable<number>;
}
```

I still get no interface in the generated `.d.ts` file.

---

**Workaround**

Here is my hideous workaround.  It consists of a pre-build command and an `exe` that runs as a post-build command.  It's not pretty, but it seems to work so far.

Prebuild: (Only so we don't merge a previous version with itself when rebuilding)

```
DEL "$(TargetDir)*.d.ts"
```

Postbuild:

```
"$(SolutionDir)\TypeScriptDefMerge\bin\Debug\TypeScriptDefMerge.exe" "$(ProjectDir) " "MyTargetFile.d.ts"
```

EXE:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TypeScriptDefMerge {
    class Program {
        // 1st argument must be the project directory path.
        // 2nd argument must be the target file name.
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Write(args.Length);
            Console.Read();

            if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("args");
            if (args.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException("Must have exactly 2 arugments.");

            var projectDir = args[0];
            var outputName = args[1];

            //Source definition files must be in this subdirectory
            //I use "\Internal" for my scripts and "\External" for 3rd-party scripts
            var sourceDir = projectDir + "\\Scripts\\Internal";

            //Output must be in this subdirectory
            var outputDir = projectDir + "\\bin\\Debug";

            var temp1 = outputDir + "\\TEMP1.d.ts";
            var temp2 = outputDir + "\\TEMP2.d.ts";

            File.Delete(temp1);
            File.Delete(temp2);

            //Create temp file holding contents of each source file
            CreateMergedFile(temp1, GetDefinitionFiles(sourceDir));

            //Create temp file holding the contents of the 1st temp file, and the normal output file
            CreateMergedFile(temp2, GetDefinitionFiles(outputDir));

            //Delete temporary files
            foreach (var f in GetDefinitionFiles(outputDir).Where(x => x != temp2)) {
                File.Delete(f);
            }

            //Rename final file
            File.Move(temp2, outputDir + "\\" + outputName);
        }

        //Get all definition files in the given directory
        static string[] GetDefinitionFiles(string directory) {
            return Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                .Where(x => x.EndsWith(".d.ts"))
                .ToArray();
        }

        //Concatenate all the given files to a new file at the given path.
        static void CreateMergedFile(string outputPath, string[] sourcePaths) {
            using (var temp = File.CreateText(outputPath)) {
                foreach (var f in sourcePaths) {
                    temp.Write(File.ReadAllText(f));
                    temp.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Seriously, there has to be something better than this.  Was it not expected that people would want to reuse interfaces?  Please let me know if you can come up with anything less clunky.

Also, note that this does not acknowledge "exclude from project" and is entirely directory based.

Comment: Interfaces have no equivalent in neither ES5 nor ES6 so there's no way to transform them to JavaScript. I think the easiest way to check that an "object implements interface" is to create a dummy class that implements the interface (with empty method bodies) you want and then check `obj instanceof DummyClass` to see whether an object is implements the interface.

Comment: I don't want them to be in the Javascript output, just the .d.ts file output, so I can keep using them in other Typescript projects that reference this one.

Comment: The interfaces are type definitions for the 3rd party Javascript package that I need to consume from Typescript.

Comment: Ahh sorry, interface should be exported to `d.ts` automatically if you defined them with `export` keyword. I'm actually using interfaces from own `d.ts` a lot. I think we need to see more of your code, it's hard to tell where's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about using `declare module IS_Interface`? I don't think you need it at all. The doc says `In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module.` Are you actually importing the module anywhere?

Comment: You've got four or five questions in this question. Can you try focusing this down to a single one?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - My focus here is really on the first question: "Is there a way to output interface definitions?"

Comment: So, perhaps you can [edit] the question to narrow the focus? Frankly I'm having a hard time seeing the forest for the trees, so to speak.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're defining the interface in `*.d.ts` file? Even though it's an interface it goes to `.ts` file just like any other class. You should let TypeScript generate all `*.d.ts` for you with `TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations`.